# Generate PDF files from view with Images from network URL in Android

Tags: android, pdf-generation, android-glide

I am generating a PDF file using the native PDF Libraries (android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument)

the document should contain a header that is a static imageView, a few textviews, and a RecyclerView with a bunch of images,

everything except the recyclerview is displayed correctly,

the recyclerview is using the Glide library to load the images but they are not loaded nor displayed,  I tried pre-fetching them using the library but it also does nothing,

here is the code for creating the pdf

```
    public File createPDF(PostDB postDB) {
    int addition = 0;
    String postDBContent = postDB.getContent();
    if (postDBContent != null) {
        int estimatedLineCount = postDBContent.length() / 43;
        String[] lines = postDBContent.split("\r\n|\r|\n");
        estimatedLineCount += lines.length;
        addition = (estimatedLineCount - 43) * 60;
    }


    List<String> imagesUrls = postDB.getImagesUrls();
    for (String url : imagesUrls) {
        Glide.with(context).load(url).preload();
    }


    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = context.openFileOutput(LOCAL_PATH, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(1800, 3900 + addition + 1000, 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View content;
        if (inflater != null) {
            final int[] count = {0};
            content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pdf_layout, null);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, content);
            publisherTextView.setText(postDB.getAuthor());
            Date date = new Date(postDB.getDate());
            DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getInstance();
            String format = dateFormat.format(date);
            dateTextView.setText(format);
            titleTextView.setText(postDB.getTitle());
            contentPreviewTextView.setText(postDBContent);
            recyclerViewImages.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 2));
            recyclerViewImages.setAdapter(new PDFImageAdapter(postDB.getImagesUrls()));
            String text = postDB.getCity() + ", " + postDB.getCountry();
            location.setText(text);
            int measureWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(page.getCanvas().getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            int measuredHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(page.getCanvas().getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            content.measure(measureWidth, measuredHeight);
            content.layout(0, 0, page.getCanvas().getWidth(), page.getCanvas().getHeight());
            content.draw(canvas);

        }
        document.finishPage(page);
        document.writeTo(fOut);
        document.close();
        fOut.close();
        return new File(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + LOCAL_PATH);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("error", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

here is my code for binding the ViewHolders

```
 public void setData(String url) {
    Glide.with(imageView.getContext()).load(url)
            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    Timber.d("onLoadFailed");
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    Timber.d("onResourceReady");
                    return true;
                }
            })
            .into(imageView);
}
```

the data onBind method is called, and calls the setData method. but neither callback from Glide is ever called.

Comment: I think you need to first download all the images, cache them (for example in getCacheDir() ), and then create a PDF.

Comment: RecyclerView is not made for this. what you can do is add a LinearLayout instead of RecyclerView and add each image to it. If you use recyclerview, some images are going to be not drawn (if the height param is 'match_parent'. If you are setting it to be 'wrap_content'... why are you even using recyclerview). Anyways, you can track if all the images are downloaded by using counter. When the counter reaches all the images to be loaded, you can draw the entire layout on the canvas which eventually will be pdf. Let me know if I am unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the iText library to solve this,

here is code I use to add images for example. that way you dont need any views.

```
Rectangle pageSize = PageSize.A4;
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, context.openFileOutput(LOCAL_PATH, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
document.open();
 document.setPageSize(pageSize);
   document.addCreationDate();
   document.addAuthor(context.getString(R.string.pdf_creator));
   document.addCreator(context.getString(R.string.pdf_creator));
Image image = Image.getInstance(filename);
   image.scaleToFit(300f, 150f);
   image.setAbsolutePosition(absoluteX, absoluteY);
   document.add(image);
document.close();
```